# FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

```
function Chat() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("")
    const [seed, setSeed] = useState("")
    const {personid} = useParams()
    const [personname, setPersonname] = useState("")
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    const [{user}, dispatch] = useStateValue()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (personid) {
        db.collection("people")
        .doc(personid)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => 
            setPersonname(snapshot.data().name));

        db.collection("people")
        .doc(personid)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => 
            setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc =>doc.data()))
            )
        }
    }, [personid])

    useEffect(() => {
        setSeed(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000))
    }, [personid])

    const sendmessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("The input is ", input);
        
        db.collection("people").doc(personid).collection("messages").add({
            message: input,
            name: user.displayName,
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        })

        setInput("")
    }
```

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3fcP.png)

I get the error in the picture below when I try to run that function.
I have tried using google cloud firestore's timestamp as an alternative but I don't know what the problem with this is.

Comment: First off, I don't see the code that actually calls `addDoc`. but my guess would be on line 48 when you call `.doc(personid)`, perhaps `personid` is undefined?  Check the value, and the docs for that method to see if you're using it correctly

Comment: I didn't write the code that calls addDoc and that's why I'm confused. Also personid isn't undefined because it worked perfectly fine before adding lines 16-23.

Comment: Please add the error message as text in your question, in such a way others can find it through search engines.

Comment: I will definitely do that next time. The error was with `user.displayName` . Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message indicates that the value of the `name` property of the object you pass to the [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) method is undefined.

This value is `user.displayName` and, as you will see in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), you should "ensure that the Auth object isn't in an intermediate state —such as initialization— when you get the current user".

For that, either you use the `onAuthStateChanged()` observer and put the desired business logic in a `if (user) {}` block, as shown in the doc, OR, you manually check that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is not null before doing `user.displayName`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the user was okey.
I found out that there is no difference, but this solved the issue:

```js
function postToFirebase(origObj) {
  let string = JSON.stringify(origObj);
  let newObj = JSON.parse(string);

  doc(db, collection, newObj)
}
```

I know, it is weird, but works...